# Can't resize external window

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, resize, window

I'm trying to resize (or better said, double the size) the window of a program that can be downloaded from **[here](http://tamagotchi.chez.com/)**, which is a simulator of the classic [Tamagotchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi) handheld digital game.

The problem is that I'm unable to do so. I can retrieve the window handle and I can identify the window by its class name if needed, but I tried both using **MoveWindow** and **SetWindowPos** functions with no results. I also tried with external programs like **[AutoSizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/AutoSizer/)** and some AutoHotkey scripts with no results either.

This is the window, with class name: `ThunderRT6FormDC`:

[image]

And seeying the image above, it seems strange that the **GetWindowRect** function returns me the next position and size:

> {X=960, Y=540, Width=960, Height=540}

I'm not sure what I'm missing with this kind of 'special' window to be able resize it...

How could one accomplish this task in C# or VB.NET?.

Comment: Maybe the window is a fixed size and therefore it ignores any messages that try and resize the window.

Comment: Thanks for comment but I don't think so since i can't set its window position either.

Comment: Programs can also ignore any requests to change position too.  I think the fact that you've tried other methods that also don't work, suggests that nothing will work.

Comment: What I meant is there is no apparent reason why the developer would like to restrict/ignore window position changes via WM_MOVE messages... then I think the logical thing is to think that neither ignores WM_SIZE messages.

Comment: "no apparent reason" - that you know of.  The developer might have decided that there was no reason for anyone to ever need to 'double the size' of the main window, so they didn't implement the code to do it.

Comment: Well, in that case I will suppose It is a kind of restriction that could be identified in some way to determine whether that is or is not he real problem with this Window... maybe you have any suggestion about (that does not imply reverse engineering the executable file)?.

Comment: You could contact the author of the program, or use [Resource Hacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Hacker) to adjust things, or halve the resolution of the display.

Comment: Thanks but **Resource Hacker** does not show any kind of useful resources to manipulate. Also, I noticed that if I double the size of the 'front.png' image (the thing with purple and white colors of the image I shared) that is in the directory of the program, the program's size remains the same. About changing the screen resolution, of course that is not a viable solution for me since what I would like to do is adjust the program's window size to see it better in my screen resolution.

Comment: Contacting the author seems not viable neither since the last program update was on 2016, and in case of the developer reads and responds any message from mine in the near future in months or years, maybe at the end he wouldn't implement a resize feature... I don't think I can't depend on the author, because I don't want to see how years pass without a solution for this, more in case of I could do something to implement a workaround for this, sonner than waiting for a uncertain response and update.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I was thinking more along the lines of perhaps the author would give you access to the source code for you to make the changes. You could ask nicely :)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1044807/495455 **If the SWP_SHOWWINDOW or SWP_HIDEWINDOW flag is set, the window cannot be moved or sized** using `SetWindowPos()`

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson Thanks for the tip, but I dont pass those restrictive flags to **SetWindowPos** function when trying to reposition and resize the window.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Just speculating but even if you manage to resize the window, it does not guarantee that the content in the window will be scaled **automagically**. In the end, as the window class name `ThunderRT6FormDC` exposes, this is a *-possibly aged-* win32 application written in VB6. So, I would't expect a miraculous scaling. This could be the reason developer choose to lock the window's size.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Thanks for the info about that kind of class name. I used a commercial program with name **VB Decompiler** and I can see the contents (the code) of the Forms. The forms have very big widths and heights, the author seems to use **SetWindowRgn** function with a fixed size, probably as a trick to make the form invisible and show only the loaded image(s), which have a fixed size. Probably that's why if I double-size a image (eg. front.png), it is shown cropped when loaded in the program.

Comment: Maybe If I double the size all the image files and also the size of the region specified in **SetWindowRgn** function, and If I manage to recompile after decompile, maybe that could do the trick... who knows. I will try to check first in a hexadecimal editor that maybe could be easier to find and change the values because I don't have the required skills in IDA or other program to manipulate assembly instructions. And well, since this questions seems not to have any kind of programmatic solution via .NET code, then I don't expect any answer to this bounty.

Comment: I can find the **SetWindowRgn** string in a hex editor but... nothing more useful. Maybe is there a exchange community focused to reverse engineering and on which the user can request things like this?.

Comment: The reason why you can not change the size is because the program uses **UpdateLayeredWindow** function to draw the window in order for the transparency to work. Basically there is no "window" to resize. You just tell the **system**, take that image with this size and draw it in that position. The system does the rest. You need to intercept the **UpdateLayeredWindow** function and change the image and size.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the window handle, you can try something like this:

```
Public Declare Auto Function MoveWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer, ByVal redraw As Boolean) As Boolean
```

Calling it

```
MoveWindow(<Handle>, <X>, <Y>, <Width>, <Height>, True)
```